# Dired+: diredp-dired-recent-dirs not working correctly

Tags: dired, recentf

Linux Mint 21

Emacs 27.1

package Dired+, Version: 2023.01.14

```
1. M-x diredp-dired-recent-dirs
2. Dired (buffer name): my-buffer
```

Here result:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the count of recent folders = 10.

OK. Now I go to folder **temp**

[image]

And open folder  **myfolder** (press ENTER)

Now I again use this commands:

```
1. M-x diredp-dired-recent-dirs
2. Dired (buffer name): my-buffer
```

[image]

As you can see, nothing changed. In this list not exist folder **myfolder**.
The count of recent folders are still = 10

P.S.
In folder **myfolder** exist one file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2b.el):

> A directory is recent if any of its files is recent.